# Save a dictionary key as a variable

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, key, eval

I'm working on a small framework and I've found a place where it would be beneficial to save a dictionary key as variable.

The problem I have is that the dictionary may have any number of layers, so it's not just a case of storing the final key. For example in the below I am accessing ['dig']['result'], but that could equally be ['output'] or ['some']['thing']['strange']

```
    if result:
        if self.cli_args.json:
            pprint(result)
        else:
            print result['dig']['result']
```

I could save the key as a string and use eval() in something such as:

```
key="['test']"
test_dict = { "test" : "This works" }
eval("test_dict" + key)
>>> 'This works'
```

But eval is really dirty right? :-)

Is there a nice / pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle an arbitrary depth of key nesting, you can iterate over a sequence (e.g. tuple) of the keys:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}
>>> d['a']['b']['c']
'd'
>>> keys = ('a', 'b', 'c')  # or just 'abc' for this trivial example
>>> content = d
>>> for k in keys:
    content = content[k]


>>> content
'd'
```

Comment: This looks very promising

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def access(o,path):
...   for k in path.split('/'):
...     o = o[k]
...   return o
... 
>>> access({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}},'a/b/c')
'd'
```

Comment: If you make `path` a sequence (e.g. `access({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}, 'abc')` or `access({'a': {'b': {'c': 'd'}}}, ('a', 'b', 'c'))`) you can factor out the split, and allow `/` in keys.